# syntax error : missing ']' before ';' Array declaration error in C

Tags: c, arrays, array-initialization

i am writing in c, using Visual c++.

The compiler gives me the errors with the code below:

```
#define SIZE 3;
int myMatrix[SIZE][SIZE];
void funcMatrix(int M[SIZE][SIZE]);
```

The errors i get:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ']' before ';' 
error C2059: syntax error : ']'
```

Ive tried declaring the constant differently, inside main and outside. It still doesn't work.
Would really appreciate it if someone can help me out...

Comment: `#define SIZE 3;` remove the `;`.

Answer (score 11):

You should use `#define SIZE 3`.

Preprocessor works as a raw string substitution, so with `#define SIZE 3;` your `SIZE` is replaced with `3;` and you get:

```
int myMatrix[3;][3;];
void funcMatrix(int M[3;][3;]);
```

as a final result, hence the errors. This is a common error, then you get used to place `;` at the end of C expression. However the [preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) `#define`-s  are not C code actually, but a simple (or not so simple) string processing operation which occurs before compilation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. Appreciate it. Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 3):

In your code `SIZE` will be replaced by the define in this case `3;` so you'll have

```
int myMatrix[3;][3;];
void funcMatrix(int M[3;][3;]);
```

Which causes a syntax error, so use `#define SIZE 3` (without the `;`) instead of `#define SIZE 3;`.

Answer (score 3):

A `#define NAME` literally inserts whatever value comes after NAME.

Your macro expands to

```
int myMatrix[3;][3;];
```

Remove the `;` in the macro definition.

Answer (score 1):

you change :

```
#define SIZE 3;
```

to

```
#define SIZE 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `;` after the `#define SIZE 3`.

`#define`s don't require a semicolon

Answer (score 1):

`#define SIZE 3` not `#define SIZE 3;`

Answer (score 1):

You can see what the compiler sees.
It can be a mess if you don't comment out included header files,
and I don't know how to do it in Visual C++,
but with GCC you run

```
gcc -E xx.c > xx.e
```

and you see what your code expands to after the #define's are processed.
There must be some way to do that with Visual C++ too.
Then you can still compile the .e file as c code.